# why is my XOR operation only implemented on half of my text file

Tags: c, file-io, xor

I am trying to XOR a file. I read in the file which consists of 1 line of text "this is some random text". When I perform the XOR operation I then output the XORed file which contains the value 00. When I XOR the file again and output the contents all that is in the file is "this is s". I am new to all of this so any information is helpful. I am planing on using this for .exe files and I am curious as to if this is successful for .txt files will it also work for .exe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

//XOR key
#define XOR_KEY 0x6F

void XORFile (char *infile, char *outfile){
    FILE *fp;
    char buf[4096];
    fp = fopen (infile, "r"); 
    fgets (buf, sizeof (buf), fp); //Reading from file
    printf ("File contents: %s\n", buf);


    int i;
    //XOR read file buffer
    for(i = 0; buf[i] != '\0'; i++){
        buf[i] ^= XOR_KEY;
    }

    FILE *fp2;
    fp2 = fopen (outfile, "w");
    fprintf (fp2, "%s", buf);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose (fp2);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc <= 3){
        fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s [CRYPT] [IN FILE] [OUTFILE]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    XORFile (argv[2], argv[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many lines are there in your input file? Because you only read a single line from the input file, nothing more

Comment: Also think about what happens if the result of `buf[i] ^= XOR_KEY` makes `buf[i] == 0` (the string null terminator happens to have the value `0`). Remember that the `printf` format `%s` writes a *null-terminated* string.

Comment: @sKIMO if you want xor you should treat the file as a binary file at least when you write i.e. use fwrite instead.

Comment: May be some byte of the xored text becomes `\x0`. I think that is better you write the output file using the fwrite function.

Comment: The byte you use to xor the data is 0x6F ("o"), when a byte containing char 'o' is xored with 0x6F ('o') its contents becomes '\x0'.

Comment: Remember that "C-Strings" are 0 terminated array of char and fprintf %s writes "C-Strings" ...

Comment: currently I was just using a single line for testing purposes, thank you all so much for your help, rookie mistakes made, however interesting food for thought, I have accepted Craigs answer below and shall spend time studying the information received, thank you all again

Comment: regarding: `fp = fopen (infile, "r");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "fopen for reading failed" );`  followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: the use of: `#define XOR_KEY 0x6F` seems incorrect as the first command line parameter is the desired encryption key

Comment: regarding: `fprintf (fp2, "%s", buf);`  After the XOR operation, the data in `buf[]` is unlikely to be printable.  Therefore, strongly suggest using `fwrite()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `fread` instead of `fgets`. You need to treat the input and output as *binary*.

And, you want to loop on it to get the *entire* file.

As it is, you'll only get the first line.

This seems like encrypt/decrypt. Even if you looped on `fgets`, it will *not* work for the decrypt because the newline will have been XORed and won't give desired results.

Here's a refactored version:

```
void
XORFile(char *infile, char *outfile)
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp2;
    int rlen;
    char buf[4096];

    fp = fopen(infile, "r");
    fp2 = fopen(outfile, "w");

    while (1) {
        rlen = fread(buf,1,sizeof(buf),fp);
        if (rlen <= 0)
            break;

        // XOR read file buffer
        for (int i = 0; i < rlen;  ++i)
            buf[i] ^= XOR_KEY;

        fwrite(buf,1,rlen,fp2);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```